# Vertically Align <a> text inside a div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I am having trouble vertically aligning the 's text inside a div.

This is what I have. I need to center "Next" inside the blue box:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli);

/*Makes the little side arrow*/
.open {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -1000px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all ease-out 0.6s;
}
.open:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #ccc inset;
  transition: all ease-out 0.6s;
}
.tutorial-box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 238px;
  top: 75px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.slider-turn p, .tutorial-box h1{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.tutorial-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  top: 28px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 14px 10px 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #f3f3f3 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.tutorial-box p {
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #a8aab2;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.tutorial-box .bottom {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.tutorial-box .bottom .btn-2 {
  flex: 3;
  -webkit-flex: 3;
  -ms-flex: 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #373942;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
}
.tutorial-box .bottom span {
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.next {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #6cb5f3;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.next:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #6BA5D6;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.next:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5F8AAF;
}
.slider-tutorial-box {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-turn {
  width: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- TUTORIAL -->
<div class="tutorial-box">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <span class="close"></span>
  
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-turn">
      <p>
        Here, under the Company tab, is where you will do most of the company managment.<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="btn-2">
      <span>Step 2/?</span>
    </div>
    <a href="/tutorial/3" class="allowedLink next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how I can center the text vertically to the center of the div.

Thank you very much. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you already did that for `.tutorial-box .bottom span` so, do the same thing for .next

```
.next{
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and possibly most easy way would be to add the 'center' and '/center' tag before and after the text you want, and after each letter use '/br' to move to the next line. this will add some bulk, but would be considerably easier than other methods.

```
<center>
    'letter'</br>'next letter'</br>'next letter'</br>
</center>
```

repeating the letter and break for all letters

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>` instead of `<br>`?

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you could also add "div" tags around the "a" tag. you would have to modify the 'height' and 'width' to make it vertical for you. I would use px for this and not '%' or 'em'. add this to them:

```
<div style="height: /* modify this */100px; width: /* and this*/20px;">
    <a href="/tutorial/3" class="allowedLink next">Next</a>
</div>
```

this may not be AS compatible cross platform though.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

`.next {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}`

A nice trick that works both vertically and horizontally.